# Wordpress - How to load a post into an iFrame?

Tags: wordpress, post, iframe

I need to load a single Wordpress post into an iFrame…

How to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this within the context of a WordPress Post or Page, or on an external website?

Comment: I'm doing this in the index.php (Main Loop)… at the end of the page I've got an iFrame where I would like to load a single wordpress post. 
This iFrame will open in full screen and show only the post content without header and footer.

I've got the standard wordpress load function:
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> …
and at the end of the index.php an iframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A starting point, I tried this a while ago, and wasn't impressed by how it interacted with the theme.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-put-an-iframe-on-a-wp-page

Or, install a plugin that does this for Posts/Pages, and use it to see what it generates, and modify your code in index.php to work properly.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/embed-iframe/

Either way the url to get to your post should be included in the iframe src.

Comment: It could be good, but I would like something like this:

<iframe src =" THE PERMALINK OF THE POST I'VE CLICKED " width="100%" height="100%"> </iframe>

The iframe src should be dynamic, depending on what post title i've clicked.

Comment: My first thought after reading your answer to my question above, is that this is a PHP issue, not WordPress. Sounds like you need to set a PHP variable in the loop with the permalink you want from the main loop. Then open another php block in the iframe and set the src to the permalink value you saved from the loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: Mmmm.. your suggestion seems very good. I'm just a designer, not programmer… so I'll try immediately your method! Thanks

Comment: The saved value could be as simple as $savedId = $post->ID; then you build an appropriate url in your iframe getting the post id to complete the URL.

Comment: Ok, I've added this:
<?php $savedId = $post->ID; ?>

and this for the iframe:
<iframe frameborder="no" allowtransparency="true" width="960px" height="520px" scrolling="no" src="http://localhost:8888/?p=<?php echo $savedId ?>"></iframe>

It works, but load the oldest project id… i would like the iframe to load the post who i go hover… and if possible not getting the ID but the url.

Comment: I'm not completely understanding what your ultimate goal is. Are you reloading the index page with the clicked post, from the previous index page, in the iframe at the bottom of the index page? If so, I haven't done anything like that, with passing posts around between pages. All I can think of is, save the post id into the cookie, and retrieve it from the cookie when the page is reloaded. This would still occur in PHP code. More detail about what you are ultimately trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: I've a list of posts…
When I click on one of this posts, I would like to display his content into an iframe.
Sorry for my english...

Comment: We've gotten a warning about extended discussions in comments, but your reputation is too low to start a chat. I'm not sure why you want to display the post in an iframe on the index page after a click. A click of a post by default changes to the single post page with comment options. Displaying the clicked post in an iframe at the bottom of the same page, index, would change default behavior as far as I can see. Is that truly what you want to do? If so, I don't know how, without doing some research myself, to make that invasive a change.

Comment: I've tried this solution and worked for me:

<a class="trick" rel="<?php the_permalink() ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
     
     <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $(".trick").click(function(){
            var post_link = $(this).attr("rel");
            $('#postframe').css("display","block");
            $('#postframe').attr("src", post_link); 
            $('body').css("overflow","hidden");
        return false;
        });

     });
  </script>

I've used query to change src attribute of iframe.

Comment: Cool! Glad you figured it out.